# didRangeBeacons gives empty array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

in my projects i detecting the beacon devices.here in delegate method it gives empty array value

this gives empty array value:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
NSLog(@"beacons list %@ ",beacons);
}
```

**Updated:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSUUID *uuid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:UUID];
    clBeconRegion=[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"BluetoothExample"];
    [locManager startMonitoringForRegion:clBeconRegion];
    clBeconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the correct UUID for your beacons?

Comment: Yes.i'm setting the correct UUID

Comment: Will you please show the code you use to set up beacon ranging?  This should include: region construction, setting the CLLocationManager delegate, requesting location permissions, and adding a permission string in your .plist file.   It would also be helpful if you could verify that you can detect the transmitting beacon using an off-the-shelf detector app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8)

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In order to get didRangeBeacons to return a non empty array, you need to call the following method:

```
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
```

Additionally, I would ensure that the beacon near you has the same UUID, and you have entered NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your info.plist. Also make sure you have created your locationManager and set its delegate.

Comment: what are you using to broadcast the beacon signal?

Comment: ipad mini & beacon real device

Comment: i tried this also [locManager requestStateForRegion:clBeconRegion]; it gives the CLRegionStateOutside & CLRegionStateUnknown only,help me

Comment: It appears that your beacon isnt actually broadcasting, or at least not the signal you are looking for. Please verify that your beacon is actually broadcasting the specified signal, and that your iPad mini has bluetooth turned on and has allowed location always access

Comment: i checked another app the beacon is finding in that app & i checked the bluetooth is on & location always access